# make EditText below TextView

Tags: android

I am trying to make each editText stick to its width and be placed exactly below the score I tried to make them each take have of the width of the screen but the white space of the editText took the whole space.

they are both child LinearLayout of a vertical LinearLayout

[image: here is a screenshot]

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightScoreTV"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftScoreTV"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/leftET"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rightET"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just make your edit text with weight same as your text view

Comment: I can't understand what you want to say,please put a screenshot that you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightScoreTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/leftET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftScoreTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rightET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:minWidth="70dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I tried what you suggested but when I set the width of the EditText to "match_parent" the field takes the whole screen it didn't stick with width of 70dp

Answer (score 1):

You have used `wrap_content` for your `layout_with`. From the docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

- MATCH_PARENT, which means the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
- WRAP_CONTENT, which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding).

Answer (score 0):

**use this:**

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use layout_weight for your two EditTexts

```
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
```